# Why is my RoR link pointing to the wrong controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I have the following in my `projects_controller.rb`:

```
def destroy
    @project = Project.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    @project.destroy
    redirect_to projects_url
end
```

And I have the following in my `routes.rb` file:

```
delete "projects/:id", to: "projects#destroy", as: "destroy_project"
```

I have the following link (inside the `show.html.erb` file):

```
<%= link_to destroy_project_path(@project), method: :delete, class: "btn-gradient btn-red" do %>
    <span>Delete Project</span>
<% end %>
```

Upon clicking the button, the page reloads. The `show` action is called upon clicking the button. I've added console logs in each method, and it is clear that **the destroy action is never called**.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you check your terminal, does your server receive a get or a delete request? It looks like your link isn't getting the http method set correctly

Comment: You're correct-- nothing shows up. Would you know how I could debug this?

Answer (score 0):

the [`link_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper receives 2 different sets of hashes for the options.

The first set is for things like the http method, and the second for the html attributes (class, id and so on)

The way you wrote it, you probably have `method=delete` in your query params, which is wrong. You have to explicitly enclose the `method: :delete` within its own options hash:

```rb
<%= link_to destroy_project_path(@project), { method: :delete }, class: "btn-gradient btn-red" do %>
    <span>Delete Project</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I'm starting to assume something is wrong with my project. I have the same lines of code in other projects working just fine.

Comment: do those links also have class names or other html attributes? because that matters. Also I don't get why you are explicitly setting the delete action in your routes, instead of letting rails defining it. Which rails version are you using? Do you have in your routes other things defined for projects (resource or namespaces?) if so, please provide that information in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you use rails 7 with turbo framework you can try below for buttons.

```
<%= button_to "Delete this project", destroy_project_path(@project), method: :delete %>
```

Or you can try below for links.

```
 <%= link_to destroy_project_path(@project.id) ,  data: { turbo_method: :delete }  do %>      
    <span>Delete Project</span>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem that you are having is with the JS. there is a problem where something is not loading properly.

For testing try to remove your JS and use something like this

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js" %>
```

When you get the delete method working, then you can debug where in your JS there is a problem.

at this time there is not sufficient info on your question to be able to know what it is.